# How to keep fonts unchanged when exporting graphics from draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I used `Helvetica` font for plain text and Latex equations in `draw.io`, with bold and italic styles. However, when exporting to file, the fonts look different and all italics become normal.

I tried `svg`, `png`, `jpg` and `pdf`. None works. `svg` even lost all the Latex equations.

Answer (score 2):

[See this FAQ entry](https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/math-typesetting):

> While all export formats except SVG are supported, some mathematical
> symbols or certain formatting, such as italic, may be missing in PDFs
> and PNGs. This is a known issue. As a workaround, use File, Print and
> save as PDF or take a screenshot to create a PNG.

Comment: In fact, I tried system pdf printer and `save to pdf` in `chrome`. The style is kept but the font size becomes large and the background color of text is missing.